# Add EMODnet Bathymetry layer on the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have been testing OpenLayers and got already some layers working. Now I would like to add sea depths layer on the map. However following their example does not show any layers. Am I doing something wrong?

I have successfully added satellite layer using this code:

```
var satelliteLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 19
  })
});
```

After that I am just performing this `map.addLayer(satelliteLayer);`

Following EMODnet Bathymetry example, I have added this one:

```
var seaDepthLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  extent: [-36, 25, 43, 85],
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'https://ows.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/wms',
    // refer to the section layer name to find the name of the layer 
    params: { 'LAYERS': 'mean_atlas_land' }
  })
});
```

Adding their layer in addition to others does not produce any change in my existing maps:

```
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
map.addLayer(seaDepthLayer);
map.addLayer(nauticLayer);
```

https://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/services/

Comment: If your view in we mercator you will need to specify the extent in view projection `extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-36, 25, 43, 85], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')`

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be working! It just the quality of layer image. If zoomed in, quite large pixels